# LineString Feature showing inconsistently, but will be eventually drawn if zoomed out far enough from

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm having an issue getting LineString features to show up consistently.  Here's the gist, I draw several lines and zoom to fit this content.  When the page first loads sometimes the lines will be displayed and sometimes they won't.  I can't seem to find any real reason as to why they don't show sometimes.  I did notice however, that if I zoom out far enough the will pop in, then I zoom right back to the same starting level and they remain visible.  The odd thing is the data is always there as are the features, I can see them if I use the getFeatures() method.  Does anyone know why this is happening or what I could try to address this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: missing gist. add the link.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a link I can share, this is for a private company's IP.  I can however describe the issue in more detail.

Simply put, draw a bunch of lines and stick images on their endpoints.  Next render the map and zoom fit down to those lines and images.  In my case this is usually around zoom level 18.  For me, the lines sometimes show up, sometimes don't.  Now, if I manually zoom the map out a bit, the lines will show up.  Hopefully, this helps clear up the description a bit.

Comment: That should be working for normal cases. so in this case, we need your code to figure the error out easier. :) if that's is happening with minimal sample data, that must be OL's problem.